# Scan QR code from phone camera

Tags: android, ios, qr-code, zbar, zbar-sdk

I was looking for a QR scanner with a overlay using Zbar SDK and I've gone through few sites and the `Zbar` documentation and understand this can be done in following way

```
ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.cameraOverlayView =myOverlay;
```

My problem in doing this is that I am developing an app using `Kony framework tool/IDE` to help develop for both iOS and android

Now I have camera with overlay developed in `Kony` and required API to read QR code from camera, is this possible?

Do we have such an API in `Zbar SDK`? for Android and iOS

Comment: what does android tag mean?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619113-cameraoverlayview

Comment: Vyacheslav, i was look for similar requirement for Android as well